# How to hide a publicity after user has realoded the page x times Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

On my website, on the index page, I have a bootstrap modal that shows publicities to the user when the page is loaded. I would like to hide this modal when the user would loaded the page more than 5 times, to not anoy the user.

Is there a way to do that? With session tricks?

Any sugestion? I don't find anything about this or I don't know how to find it.

Thank you!

Comment: I would say use local storage for that. keep this browser side only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AkhzarJaved said, you can do this with JS `localStorage`.

```js
let pubViews = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('pub_views')) || 0;
if (pubViews < 5) {
     document.querySelector('#publicities').style.display = 'block'; // or other display value
     localStorage.setItem('pub_views', (pubViews + 1));
}
```

Comment: Didn't know that, I did some search about this and everythings works like I wanted, thank you! :)